# C# static classes. How to improve the code?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods

As an ex-Matlab user, I have been finding it hard to work with classes because in Matlab I am not used to working with classes.

Now, I have C# Winforms project, and it is working okay but I am feeling that it has code smells and has wrong design patterns. Most of the time what I am doing is creating static classes and implementing all the relevant methods in that class. At the end of the day, my project has all full with these static classes.

It would be great if you look at these pieces of code and give some suggestions about what can be done to improve the code.

- Let's say I have the main window and it has 3 buttons (Add, Update,
  Delete record in database)
- Then, I have a static class that holds all relevant methods.

So my question is what would be the better way to accomplish the same thing?

**Main.cs**

```
private void AddNewRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseOperations.AddRecord();
}

private void UpdateRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseOperations.UpdateRecord();
}

private void DeleteRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseOperations.DeleteRecord();
}
```

**DatabaseOperations.cs**
This is the static class that holds all relevant methods.

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public static class DatabaseOperations
    { 
        internal static void AddRecord()
        {
            // Implements a method that adding a new record in database
        }

        internal static void UpdateRecord()
        {
            // Implements a method that updating an existing record in database
        }

        internal static void DeleteRecord()
        {
            // Implements a method that deleting an existing record in database
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For questions about code smells etc. (seeking a review) go to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is a problem you share with lots of people coming from a pure functional language background. I feel this is not answerable on SO. You should read up on OOP in general and OOP in C# specifically. And don't try to do what you did in Matlab. "Empty the cup" and do things the C#/OOP way.

Comment: As @EpicKip wrote, this is either a CodeReview question OR a [ProgrammersSO](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) question. I'm inclined to say it's the latter (since the code you show is merely an example of what you generally do, not a specific case you need help with).

Comment: If this approach works for you - it is fine. Only problems I can see is if you write or later decide to write unit tests for you code. With static methods you will not be able to "mock" code not related for particular unit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to do Object Oriented way. 
Here is something can quickly do

- Change the DatabaseOperations class and method to be public
  non-static.
- In Main.cs add a constructor to have DatabaseOperation as
  input
- In Program.cs initialize Main.cs using new constructor.
- ...

By this time i think bullet points wont work so here is a code example:
https://github.com/duongthaiha/WinformOODIExample

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the example, it is very clear. What is the advantage of changing the code from that (the one I posted) to this?

Comment: these suggestions are pointing you on the OOP way to do it. One advange is that, using member method vs static ones, you will be able in future to use a different class (inherited from current `DatabaseOperations` class), that can implement the same methods in a different way: you don't need to rewrite the client code calling these method, but only the line when you create the instance you are calling method. I agree with @Fildor comment in your original post: you should do it in the C#/OOP way. not something can be explained in the space of a comment (neither an aswer).